# How to Remove a Title from All Category and Tags Page?

Tags: categories, tags, archives, title

I am trying to remove the  title from all my category and tags page.

So far, I have been using this code http://pastebin.com/xxmyw7BP. It works but not perfectly. The title of my category and tag page is removed. However, on my sidebar, the content in my recent posts widget also lose their titles.

What other qualifier should I add other than is_archive() so that it strictly targets only the title on the category and tag pages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that editing the loop would be the best way to do this as it keep the changes local to that php template.  Simply go into category.php (or archive.php) and tag.php, look for `<?php the_title(); ?>` and delete it or change it to `<?php //the_title(); ?>` to comment it out.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to edit those specific loops to remove the titles, that way it won't affect the lists in the widget areas.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the filter route, I would use `is_category() || is_tag()` instead of `is_archive()`. Also, you probably want to use [**`is_main_query()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query), so that your filter doesn't impact other queries (such as the recent posts query).

But the better approach would probably be just to create `category.php` and `tag.php` template files, in which you *omit* the call to `<?php the_title(); ?>` inside the Loop.